# Linkedin Api sample AdSupplyForecast does not work

Tags: linkedin-api

Nowadays I am working on Linkedin AdSupplyForecast api to follow at the below reference,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ad-supply-forecasts#find-supply-by-criteriav2

However the sample code does not work also I can not find any extra description about criteriaV2.

Standart Api sample at the below and response is '{"message":"Invalid HTTP Request","status":404}'

```
curl    -H "Authorization:Bearer XX"    -H "Content-Type:application/json"    "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adSupplyForecasts?q=criteriaV2&account=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A518121035&timeRange=(start: 1587639976000,end: 1589540776000)&campaignType=SPONSORED_UPDATES&competingBid=(bidType:CPM,bidPrice:(currencyCode:USD,amount:10))&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3AcountryGroup%3ANA))))),exclude:(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AstaffCountRanges:List(urn%3Ali%3AstaffCountRange%3A%2810001%2C2147483647%29))))"
```

I modified it and like as at the below but it send server error '{"message":"Internal Server Error","status":500}', would you share with me a correct sample of it ?

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adSupplyForecasts?q=criteriaV2&account=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:518121035&timeRange.start=1587639976000&timeRange.end=1589540776000&campaignType=SPONSORED_UPDATES&targetingCriteria.include=and:List%28%28or:%28{encoded%20urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations}:List%28{encoded%20urn:li:countryGroup:NA}%29%29%29%29&targetingCriteria.exclude=or:%28{encoded%20urn:li:adTargetingFacet:staffCountRanges}:List%28{encoded%20urn:li:staffCountRange:%2810001,2147483647%29}%29%29' \ --header 'Authorization: XXX'
```

Comment: I also suspected that I was making a mistake on targeting criteria  input but I can call the 'audienceCountsV2' endpoint service properly and I also used there 'targetingCriteria' query properly. In my opinion there is a bug/problem on this endpoint.